# tt_news pagebrowser - How to disable page selector

Tags: typo3, typoscript, tt-news

how can I show only "next" and "prev" links under the tt_news list? The typoscript already contains:

```
plugin.tt_news {
 pageBrowser {
   maxPages = 10
   showResultCount = 0
   showPBrowserText = 1
   dontLinkActivePage = 0

   showFirstLast = 0
   showRange = 0
   hscText = 1

   browseBoxWrap = <ul>|</ul>
   activeLinkWrap = <li class="active">|</li>
   disabledLinkWrap = <li>|</li>
   inactiveLinkWrap = <li>|</li>
  }
}
```

Oh and what does "hscText" stands for?

Comment: hsc stands for HtmlSpecialChars. If its on it converts chars like german umlauts to its HTML entities like ä -> &auml; 

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Which pagebrowser are you using? The one from tt_news or the one from TYPO3 (plugin.tt_news.usePiBasePagebrowser = 1)?

Comment: you didn't ask that ... "plugin.tt_news { pageBrowser {" ... says everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution gives [Daimi's Skinnablepagebrowser](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/daimi_skinnablepagebrowser) (currently alpha!) which provides additional parameters for the next and prev button. With that and by clearing the normal pagebrowser link wrappers you can only show the next and prev buttons ;D